# How to configure Harbor on k8s cluster?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, minio, harbor

I'm trying to deploy Harbor(private docker registry) on k8s cluster(provisioned by Rancher) using helm(values.yaml).
below is my valuse.yaml.

1. Network
   I have nginx front of k8s ingress nginx controller.
   nginx(http 301 redirect to https, ex. http://harbor.mydomain.com -> https://harbor.ssgadm.com)
   -> ingress-nginx -> harbor service
2. Harbor with nginx
   https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/docs/1.10/install-config/troubleshoot-installation.md#using-nginx-or-load-balancing
   Harbor team says if Harbor is running behind an nginx proxy, remove header 'X-Forwarded-Proto', so I added ingress annotation in values.yaml

Here are my problems.
1. succeeded login docker, but failed to push docker image with message : denied: requested access to the resource is denied

2. cannot see minio registry endpoint at harbor web page
   [couldn't find any endpoints!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5995m.png)

So, could you help me solve problems?

```
---
  harborAdminPassword: "admin"
  secretKey: "add-your-secret0"
  logLevel: "info"
  expose: 
    type: "ingress"
    ingress: 
      hosts: 
        core: "harbor.mydomain.com"
        notary: "harbor.notary.mydomain.com"
      annotations:
        ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
        ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
        nginx.org/server-snippets: |
          location / {
            proxy_hide_header 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
          }

          location /v2/ {
            proxy_hide_header 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
          }

          location /service/ {
            proxy_hide_header 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
          }
    loadBalancer: 
      IP: ""
    tls: 
      enabled: false
      secretName: ""
  externalURL: "https://harbor.mydomain.com"
  persistence: 
    imageChartStorage: 
      type: "s3"
      disableredirect: true
      azure: 
        accountname: ""
        accountkey: ""
        container: ""
      gcs: 
        bucket: ""
        encodedkey: ""
      s3: 
        bucket: "docker"
        region: "us-east-1"
        accesskey: "minio"
        secretkey: "minio"
        regionendpoint: "https://minio.mydomain.com"
      oss: 
        bucket: ""
        region: ""
        accesskeyid: ""
        accesskeysecret: ""
      swift: 
        authurl: "https://storage.myprovider.com/v3/auth"
        username: ""
        password: ""
        container: ""
    enabled: true
    persistentVolumeClaim: 
      registry: 
        storageClass: "nfs-provisioner"
        size: "1Gi"
        existingClaim: ""
      chartmuseum: 
        storageClass: "nfs-provisioner"
        size: "1Gi"
        existingClaim: ""
      jobservice: 
        storageClass: "nfs-provisioner"
        size: "1Gi"
        existingClaim: ""
      database: 
        storageClass: "nfs-provisioner"
        size: "1Gi"
        existingClaim: ""
      redis: 
        storageClass: "nfs-provisioner"
        size: "1Gi"
        existingClaim: ""
  jobservice: 
    jobLogger: "database"
  database: 
    type: "internal"
    external: 
      host: ""
      username: ""
      password: ""
      coreDatabase: "registry"
      clairDatabase: "clair"
      notaryServerDatabase: "notary_server"
      notarySignerDatabase: "notary_signer"
      sslmode: "disable"
      port: "5432"
  redis: 
    type: "internal"
    external: 
      host: ""
      port: "6379"
      password: ""
  clair: 
    enabled: true
  notary: 
    enabled: false
  chartmuseum: 
    enabled: true
  cert: 
    enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all [prerequisites](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/docs/1.10/install-config/installation-prereqs.md) are fulfilled.

Make sure that you have provided [certificates](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/docs/1.10/install-config/configure-https.md#provide-the-certificates-to-harbor-and-docker) to Harbor and Docker.

After generating the ca.crt, yourdomain.com.crt, and yourdomain.com.key files, you must provide them to Harbor and to Docker, and reconfigure Harbor to use them. Finally restart Docker Engine.

**To enable pushing images to docker registry please execute following commands:**

> You need to include the namespace for Docker Hub to associate it with
>   your account. The namespace is the same as your Docker Hub account
>   name. You need to rename the image to
>   YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/docker-whale.

**Tag image before pushing:**

```
$ docker tag your_image YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/your_image
```

and then you should be able to push it.

```
$ docker push YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/your_image
```

You have also duplicated `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` annotation in configuration file.

> For NGINX, an 413 error will be returned to the client when the size
>   in a request exceeds the maximum allowed size of the client request
>   body. This size can be configured by the parameter
>   client_max_body_size.

To configure this setting globally for all Ingress rules, the proxy-body-size value may be set in the NGINX ConfigMap. To use custom values in an Ingress rule define these annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
```

try to add **0m**.

Also environment sanity check: should fail without SSL, enable external ss in database:

```
sslmode=require
```

If more problem occur check logs of installed harbor:

```
$ kubectl logs -n harbor your-harbor-pod
```

Comment: Does it help ? Would you consider upvote/accept it, it will be useful for community.